# Cannot install grails plugin to local or remote maven repo

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to install my grails plugin to local or remote repo, but when I run 
mvn install -DskipTests I'd always get this message:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.9
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to development
................................
|Packaging Grails application
................................
|Plugin packaged grails-mcplugin-license-0.4.3.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.532s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 05 14:12:03 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.4.0:package-plugin           (default->package-plugin) on project McpluginLicense: Unable to copy the plugin ZIP to the   target >directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the    following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm using grails-maven plugin right from github because it solves this problem -https://jira.grails.org/browse/MAVEN-237, can it be related to my issue? How do I track it down? I tried to look at maven debug output but I didn't notice anything that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest installing the [release plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/release) and then running

```
grails maven-install
```

The documentation is [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/guide/maven.html#mavenCache).